# Optimizing 2D grid space for placing objects

Tags: algorithm, functional-programming, 2d, dynamic-programming, space

My objective is optimizing a 2D grid space reducing the unoccupied space as much as possible. The objects to place in the grid have some dimension HxW and the have some constraints to fullfill.

[image: 2D grid & objects]

As you can see in the picture I have several objects to put in the grid, each of one has a priority (they must be placed in the grid respecting a priority, if it won't fit, then a lower priority smaller object will be placed in the grid) and also a requisite.

Is there anything that can help to achieve this? Some theoric algorithm, some library in any programming language etc... Something to not start from the beginning.

Many thank#!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [rectangle packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangle_packing). There are many variations on the problem. The linked Wikipedia article describes three variations, with links to references that include algorithm descriptions and code.